# how to change php page url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the url from

```
  http://localhost/brand/2-BBB.html
```

to

```
 http://localhost/brand/BBB-2.html
```

appreciate if you can help me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^brand/([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ test.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Have you tried to google it? https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @Mech I tried but no results
if I use htaccess above, it works
but when I change the ID behind it can't work (.*)-[0-9]+)]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851087/how-to-make-a-url-seo-friendly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've changed the URLs in your application to the new `/BBB-2.html` version, then you just need to change your directive like this:

```
RewriteRule ^brand/(.+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ test.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Note the `$2` backreference.